# Error in DAG destructor

Tags: c++, destructor, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a Dag class (Directed Acyclic Graph) that contains a vector of raw pointers to objects of the class Node. This vector is called `m_roots` and consists of all the nodes that do not have offsprings. (But they can have up to two parents) The Node objects form binary trees of sorts.
The member attributes of Nodes are:

```
int m_indiv;
Node * m_dad;
Node * m_mom;
std::vector<Node * > m_offsprings;
int m_generat;
```

So although the structure is acyclic, I have pointers in both directions.
The Dag constructor launches a recurrence that creates the Nodes from a the data contained in a map. Here is the recurrent part:

```
void Node::recNode(const map<int, pair<int, int> > &mapPed, map<int, Node * > &mapDup, const vector <int> &sampleListe, vector<Node * > &sample)
{

    if (find (sampleListe.begin(), sampleListe.end(), this->m_indiv) != sampleListe.end()) {
        sample.push_back(this);
    }
    pair<int, int> parents;


    if (parents.first!=0) { //0 is a reserved integer for missing data, pointer stay to NULL (nullptr)
        if (mapDup.find(parents.first) == mapDup.end() || !(mapDup[parents.first])) {
            m_dad=new Node(parents.first);
            if (mapDup.find(parents.first) != mapDup.end()) { 
                mapDup[parents.first]=m_dad;
            }
            m_dad->recNode(mapPed, mapDup, sampleListe, sample);
        }
        else {
            m_dad=mapDup[parents.first];
        }
        m_dad->m_offsprings.push_back(this); //add the pointer to this node in the dads list of offspring
    }

    //do the same for the second parent
    if (parents.second!=0) {
        if (mapDup.find(parents.second) == mapDup.end() || !(mapDup[parents.second]) ) {
            m_mom=new Node(parents.second);
            if (mapDup.find(parents.second) != mapDup.end()) {
                mapDup[parents.second]=m_mom;
            }
        m_mom->recNode(mapPed, mapDup, sampleListe, sample);
        }
        else {
            m_mom=mapDup[parents.second];
        }
        m_mom->m_offsprings.push_back(this); //add the pointer to this node in the moms list of offspring
    }

}
```

My Dag destructor launches the recursive destruction:

```
Dag::~Dag()
{
    for (int i(0); i<m_roots.size();++i) {
        delete m_roots[i];
    }
}
```

The Node destructor should be doing the actual destruction:

```
Node::~Node()        

{
    if(m_dad) {
        Node* dummyD=m_dad;
        for (int i(0); i<m_dad->m_offsprings.size();++i) {
            if (m_dad->m_offsprings[i]) {
                m_dad->m_offsprings[i]->m_dad=nullptr;
            }
        }
        delete dummyD;
    }
    if(m_mom) {
        Node* dummyM=m_mom;
        for (int i(0); i<m_mom->m_offsprings.size();++i) {
            if (m_mom->m_offsprings[i]) {
                m_mom->m_offsprings[i]->m_mom=nullptr;
            }
        }
        delete dummyM;
    }

}
```

For some reason this is not working: I get a Seg Fault. 
The corresponding Valgrind error is:

```
InvalidRead                                     Invalid read of size 8
                                                Call stack:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h  646     0x411734: Node::~Node()
~/Dag.cpp                               138     0x409E98: Dag::~Dag()
~/main.cpp                              114     0x41062B: main
            Address 0x18 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

When debugging line per line, it breaks at the line:

```
for (int i; i<m_dad->m_offsprings.size();++i) {
```

after the first iteration. (During the first call to ~Dag() and the first call to ~Node()). The i from the for loop where it breaks just changed from 0 to 1.
The fact it breaks this early on makes it unlikely that it is a problem of cycles in the Dag... 
I also have a '__in_charg' function argument which is `<optimized out>` (despite -O0). I am not sure what it means but it seems that `Node* dummyD=m_dad;` is not read...

I am looking for the reason why it is not working, the flaw in the logic... I know that it can be done using `shared_ptr` for the mom and dad and `weak_ptr` for offsprings.

**Note:** The nomenclature parent/offspring is somewhat field specific. Here I use it in the "biological" sens: each individual has only one mom and one dad but can have from 0 to n offsprings.

Comment: please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you're never initializing `i` - you should.

Comment: May be issue itself is not in destructor code, but somewhere else: `m_roots` is not correct or graph is not really acyclic. That's why @m.s. point is important.

Comment: `m_mom->offsprings` - those are your siblings. Ignore the code for a moment. What are you even trying to do?! What are the roots nodes in ` Dag`  anyway? The youngest children or the oldest parents?

Comment: @MSalters m_mom->offsprings are me AND my siblings. roots are all the Nodes that do not have offsprings. So they are the youngest children in a sens. I am merely trying to destroy all Nodes once and once only.

Comment: @anxieux That would be actually great but I am not sure how to. The error seems to appear with certain input files and not other depending on the exact structure of the DAG.

Comment: And what is the problem to run this in debugger and check what's going on there?

Comment: Unless your "root" nodes have parents, which is pretty odd if they're roots, your destructor doesn't do anything.

Comment: @anxieux I did that but it does not really help with a diagnostic: it gives me the same call stack as Valgrind, no line number, no watches value.

Comment: @molbdnilo As pointed out in a comment, my roots have parents they do not have offsprings. I will try to make this clearer in the question. Thanks.

Comment: I believe the problem is that after you have deleted the parents, they may still be offspring of some other node which you haven't destroyed yet.

Comment: @molbdnilo Maybe but I can't figure out how. Can you think of an example of Dag where this may occur?

Comment: @Prolix: count the references, or let that do a `shared_ptr` ... see below.

Comment: Use step-by-step debugging: put breakpoint in the beginning of DAG destructor, verify that roots and graph structure is correct. After that delete nodes one-by-one and check invariants on each step.

Comment: @anxieux Wherever I put the break points in the Dag destructor it still gives me a segfault with the same stack and does not stop at the break point. And does it mean something special when the function in the call stack has 2 or 3 sets of brackets: e.g. Node::~Node() ()?

Comment: Seems like you have some trouble with building/debugging tools... Are you sure you are using "-g" build and breakpoint is properly set?

Comment: @anxieux Ok my bad. That was an editor bug. I had to quite and come back, the breakpoint was appearing on the screen but not doing it job... I added an error description of the line per line debugging in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Node::~Node()` function, seems like `this` is a one of the `m_offsprings`. So after the first iteration of the

```
for (int i(0); i<m_dad->m_offsprings.size();++i) {
    if (m_dad->m_offsprings[i]) {
        m_dad->m_offsprings[i]->m_dad=nullptr;
    }
}
```

`this->m_dad` becomes `nullptr`. After that you are trying to dereference it in `m_dad->m_offsprings.size()`.

To fix this, check that address of the current `m_dad`'s `m_offspring` is not equal to `this`. (And same for `m_mom`.)

Comment: That makes so much sense! I used the dummy ptr exactly for that purpose in the delete part but I did not think of the for loop! Thank you very much! I can't test it right now but then if I use the `dummyD->m_offsprings` pointer in the for loop instead of `m_dad->m_offsprings` it should fix it too, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct solution, but I guess even more helpful: If somehow possible, completely get rid of all the mentioned problems by using smart-pointers

```
Node
{
    int m_indiv;
    Node * m_dad;
    Node * m_mom;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node> > m_offsprings;
    int m_generat;
}
```

No, if a node is destructed (--and it is the last one pointing to the offsprings), all offspring destructors automatically get called recursively. So there's no need to write further error-prone code.

Comment: The last line of my post kind of addresses this but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

m_roots[0] and m_roots[1] share the same dad.
When you delete Node m_roots[0], its' dad and mom get deleted, as well as their whole "family". Thus, m_roots[1] becomes an orphan.

Comment: Why is it a problem that `m_roots[1]` is an orphan? Before deleting the dad, the pointers  to the dad from `m_roots[1]` should be set to `nullptr` and when deleting `m_roots[1]`, `if(m_dad)` will be false and will go take care of the mom's side. Is that wrong?

Comment: Besides, if that was the problem, the code would break later on, after the second iteration of ~Dag(). Point which is never reached. Or?

Comment: @Prolix : to answer your second comment, no, that's exactly where it would break. since m_dad is deleted you cannot access its m_offsprings vector anymore. Can you add the code where you add the parent-child relationship between two nodes ?

Comment: I posted the code that creates the Dag relationships.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Your answer was not exactly right but your comment was spot on. +1